# Silverlight Microphone Delay

Tags: silverlight, signal-processing, microphone

I'm doing real-time DSP on Silverlight microphone input in order to show a volume level while recording. My problem is the `OnSamples()` method in my `AudioSink` is only called once per 500ms. This means I can run the FFT on the stream and update the volume meter only twice per second. Visually this isn't very appealing to me.

I'm guessing this apparent 500ms "buffering" of microphone input is a limitation of Silverlight, but I thought I'd see if anyone had any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered my own question.

`AudioCaptureDevice.AudioFrameSize`